# How to Insert Values into Table through MySQLdb Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

So here I was trying to store the values of a csv file 'employee_reviews.csv' into my employees table. I'm reading through the file, storing it as a string, then splitting the elements all the way down to a 2D list which is then looped through each row. I'm pretty sure there is a more simple way of doing this. When I run my code, I get an Error ->

> cur.execute("INSERT INTO (id, company, location, dates, job_title,
>   summary, pros, cons, advice_to_management, overall_ratings,
>   work_balance_stars, culture_value_stars, career_opportunities_stars,
>   comp_benefit_stars, senior_management_stars, helpful_count, link)
>   VALUES
>   (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(int(row[0]),
>   row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8],
>   int(row[9]), row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14],
>   int(row[15]), row[16] )) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with
>   base 10: 'none'

---

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQL.connect(host="host",user="user",passwd="passwd",db="Employee_Review")
cur = mydb.cursor()
#cur.execute("CREATE TABLE employees(id INT, company VARCHAR(20), location VARCHAR(40), dates DATE, job_title VARCHAR(20), summary VARCHAR(50), pros VARCHAR(1000), cons VARCHAR(1000), advice_to_management VARCHAR(50), overall_ratings INT, work_balance_stars VARCHAR(10), culture_value_stars VARCHAR(10), career_opportunities_stars VARCHAR(10), comp_benefit_stars VARCHAR(10), senior_management_stars VARCHAR(10), helpful_count INT, link VARCHAR(75) )")

f = open("employee_reviews.csv","r")
fString = f.read()

fList = []
for line in fString.split('\n'):
   fList.append(line.split(','))

for row in fList:
   if row == fList[0]:
      continue #skip the first row for it contains the name of the columns

   cur.execute("INSERT INTO (id, company, location, dates, job_title, summary, pros, cons, advice_to_management, overall_ratings, work_balance_stars, culture_value_stars, career_opportunities_stars, comp_benefit_stars, senior_management_stars, helpful_count, link) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(int(row[0]), row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], int(row[9]), row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], int(row[15]), row[16] ))
   mydb.commit()

mydb.close()
```

The csv file can be found here:
https://inclass.kaggle.com/petersunga/google-amazon-facebook-employee-reviews/discussion

Comment: [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) is a lot easier way of handing CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

One of the values in your CSV is 'none' which couldn't be converted to an integer in one of your integer columns.